# NSPredicate doesn't filter data for long value in iOS 5

Tags: ios5, nsarray, filtering, nspredicate

I am trying to filter data from array using NSPredicate.
My array (arrLikes) contains following data from server

```
{
    "id":17,
    "likes":[
        {
        "likedBy":
            {
             "firstName":"Bob",
             "lastName":"Builder",
             "id":1
            }
        }],
    "comments":[]
}
```

I am trying to filter the data from array like below

```
long loggedInUserId = [[dictUserInfo objectForKey:@"id"] longValue];
NSPredicate *likePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %ld", loggedInUserId ];
NSArray *filteredLikeArray  = [arrLikes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:likePredicate];
```

Even if my loggedInUserId is 1 , filteredLikeArray count retruns 0.
What wrong in above code ?
Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try converting long into NSString as follows?

```
long loggedInUserId = 17;
NSString *stringUserId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", loggedInUserId];
NSPredicate *likePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@", stringUserId];
NSArray *filteredLikeArray  = [arrLikes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:likePredicate];
```

Comment: There is an "id" tag inside "likes" array, are you going to filter items inside "likes" array?

Comment: Yes... I need to filter items inside "likes" array